# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)

Tags: java

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsappinacap"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.mohammadatif:CircularImageView:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

The specific problem that happens is that I add an option to delete a post in the app that I try to do, at the moment I try to delete a post I close the app, here is the class that is responsible for doing the process of deleting the post:

```html
2019-11-02 20:40:33.460 16560-16560/com.example.whatsappinacap E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-11-02 20:40:35.085 16560-16654/com.example.whatsappinacap E/GooglePlayServicesUtil: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
2019-11-02 20:40:37.773 16560-16560/com.example.whatsappinacap E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2019-11-02 20:40:42.360 16560-16675/com.example.whatsappinacap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: FirebaseStorage-Command-1
    Process: com.example.whatsappinacap, PID: 16560
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.whatsappinacap-ffbwTZ9oNfl6I4IY8gAOPg==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.DeleteStorageTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.1.0:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

```
enter code here
```

```js
package com.example.whatsappinacap.adapters;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.whatsappinacap.R;
import com.example.whatsappinacap.ThereProfileActivity;
import com.example.whatsappinacap.models.ModelPost;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class AdapterPosts extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPosts.MyHolder>{

    Context context;
    List<ModelPost> postList;

    String myUid;

    public AdapterPosts(Context context, List<ModelPost> postList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.postList = postList;
        myUid= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_posts, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyHolder myHolder, int i) {

        final String uid=postList.get(i).getUid();
        String uEmail=postList.get(i).getuEmail();
        String uName=postList.get(i).getuName();
        String uDp=postList.get(i).getuDp();
        final String pId=postList.get(i).getpId();
        String pTitle=postList.get(i).getpTitle();
        String pDescription=postList.get(i).getpDescr();
        final String pImage=postList.get(i).getpImage();
        String pTimeStamp=postList.get(i).getpTime();

        Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(pTimeStamp));
        String pTime= DateFormat.format("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:aa", calendar).toString();

        myHolder.uNameTv.setText(uName);
        myHolder.pTimeTv.setText(pTime);
        myHolder.pTitleTv.setText(pTitle);
        myHolder.pDescriptionTv.setText(pDescription);

        try {
            Picasso.get().load(uDp).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_img).into(myHolder.uPictureIv);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

        if (pImage.equals("noImage")){
            myHolder.pImageIv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else {
            myHolder.pImageIv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                Picasso.get().load(pImage).into(myHolder.pImageIv);
            }
            catch (Exception e){

            }
        }

        myHolder.moreBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showMoreOptions(myHolder.moreBtn, uid, myUid, pId, pImage);
            }
        });
        myHolder.likeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Like", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.commentBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Comment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.shateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        myHolder.profileLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context, ThereProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("uid",uid);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showMoreOptions(ImageButton moreBtn, String uid, String myUid, final String pId, final String pImage) {

        PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(context, moreBtn, Gravity.END);

        if (uid.equals(myUid)){
            popupMenu.getMenu().add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Delete");
        }

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                int id=menuItem.getItemId();
                if (id==0){
                    beginDelete(pId, pImage);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        popupMenu.show();
    }

    private void beginDelete(String pId, String pImage) {
        if (pImage.equals("noImage")){
            deleteWithoutImage(pId);
        }
        else {
            deleteWithImage(pId, pImage);
        }
    }

    private void deleteWithImage(final String pId, String pImage) {
        final ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Deleting...");
        StorageReference picRef= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(pImage);
        picRef.delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Query fquery= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("pId").equalTo(pId);
                        fquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                                }
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                pd.dismiss();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void deleteWithoutImage(String pId) {
        final  ProgressDialog pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setMessage("Deleting...");
        Query fquery= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts").orderByChild("pId").equalTo(pId);
        fquery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    ds.getRef().removeValue();
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, "Delete successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return postList.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView uPictureIv, pImageIv;
        TextView uNameTv, pTimeTv, pTitleTv, pDescriptionTv, pLikesTv;
        ImageButton moreBtn;
        Button likeBtn, commentBtn, shateBtn;
        LinearLayout profileLayout;

        public MyHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            uPictureIv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.uPictureIv);
            pImageIv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pImageIv);
            uNameTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.uNameIv);
            pTimeTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTimeTv);
            pTitleTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pTimeTv);
            pDescriptionTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pDescriptiontTv);
            pLikesTv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.pLikeTv);
            moreBtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.moreBtn);
            likeBtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.likeBtn);
            commentBtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.commentBtn);
            shateBtn=itemView.findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
            profileLayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileLayout);
        }
    }
}
enter code here
```

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.whatsappinacap"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.github.mohammadatif:CircularImageView:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:17.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
enter code here
enter code here
```

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately - this lets those with knowledge of the language you need help with to see your question.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56228134/app-crashes-when-saving-a-cropped-photo-to-firebasestorage  (ignore the title!!)

Answer (score 4):

In general, a `NoSuchMethodError` exception means that there is a version mismatch.  Some component has been compiled against a version of the API that has the "missing" method, but the version that is used at runtime the API doesn't have the method.

In this case, it seems that the problem is that

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
```

are incompatible.

Specifically, the `firebase-storage` dependency should be `17.0.0` or later.